# AWS RDS Connection and spring boot, JPA

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jpa, amazon-rds

I connect my DB (AWS RDS) to Spring boot JPA, Then my number of connections increases dramatically.
it is 12 now, I think it works spring boot 5 + browser 5, workbench 1 +, and others?

How can I reduce my number of connections? How can I maintain this connection safely?

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for **Database connection pooling**.

Database connection pooling is a method used to keep database connections open so they can be reused and also it will be keeping the total number of connections within a limit that we are specifying.

The default connection pool in Spring Boot is **HikariCP**, all you have to do is configure it properly

Sample connection pool configuration,

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 20000     
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10     
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000     
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000 
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true
```

Comment: thank you!!  that's what i want to know